# I need to write eloquent query that return messages having specific tag

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, where-clause

```
messages Table
+----+----------+
| id |   text   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | message1 |
|  2 | message2 |
+----+----------+

tags table 

+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | valentine |
|  2 | funny     |
|  3 | santa     |
+----+-----------+

message_tag
+----+------------+--------+
| id | message_id | tag_id |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          1 |      1 |
|  2 |          2 |      1 |
|  3 |          2 |      2 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

I have written this query so far to get all messages but i cant return the 
message where tag_id = 1;

> ```
>     Message::with([
>         'tags'=>function($q){
>             $q->select("name","tag_id");
>         }
>     ])->select("id", "text")->paginate(10);
> ```

i have used where clause inside function($q){$q->where('tag_id',1)}. but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You have to include [use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins) at the top of class

```
$tagId = 1; 
$return = DB::table('message_tag')
            ->join('messages', 'messages.id', '=', 'message_tag.message_id')
            ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'message_tag.tag_id')
            ->where("message_tag.tag_id", "=", $tagId)
            ->select('messages.text', 'tags.text')
            ->get();
```

Comment: I would highly appreciate if you could see my effort and add some comment in it. I prefer more querying with eloquent models than sql style join.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `whereHas()`, assuming you set a many-to-many relationship properly:

```
$tag = 'Madhab452';
$messages = Message::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag) {
    $query->where('name', '=', $tag)
    ->select('name', 'tag_id');
})->get();
```